# In Safari or Firefox missing trailing spaces ruins requests to a server with axios

Tags: rest, axios

I am building an app with React and using `axios` there for working with APi(built with Python).

I had a weird bug, luckily I found a reason of that - all requests without trailing slash were failed with 401 error in Safari and Firefox, e.g. `/users`

I was so lucky to have one of my requests with slash and it was working well, so when I tried to add slashes to my other requests it have make them work! e.g. `/users/` etc.

It's not so complex for me to add it, but sometimes, when I am passing ids for example, it requires me to use `/users/${id}/` or `'/users/' + id + '/'` which is not cool.

My question is if it a browsers bug, or axios bug, or it could be solved on a backend server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked backend developer to check this and he fixed that on his side